C++ for Loop not showing last value in floating point increment with <= operator
I have encountered this strange behavior of <= operator in C++.
I have this code which I tested on Dev C++ also on Programiz Online compiler. Both showing same behavior.
for (float x=1; x<=2; x+=0.1)
{
    cout<<"Value of X is "<<x<<endl;
    }

By the appearance it should go from 1 to 2 by an increment of 0.1 but when I run it, it goes only upto 1.9. Same is the result when I use only less than < operator.
attached is result.


By the appearance it should go from 1 to 2 by an increment of 0.1 -- Are you familiar with 0.1 not being an exact binary floating point number?  There is a slight floating point error each time you add 0.1 to x in your loop.

Can you enlighten me?

Also, you should not write loops that use floating point values as loop counters.  If you know that you must loop n times, then you write an integer based loop that loops n times.  Inside the loop, create a temporary that divides n by 10 and use the temporary.  for (int x=10; x<=20; x++) { float temp = x / 10.0; cout<<"Value of X is "<<temp<<endl; }

This was educational purpose test and I came across this issue which I haven't seen earlier. Thanks for your time and support

For you specific case and to better see what's going on behind the scene have a look at this modified version of your code: I just increased the range a bit so you'll see values past 2 and called setprecision(15) to see more decimal places of the actual value. All suggested in the above provided answer.
https://onecompiler.com/cpp/42zzybrr4

@AdnanAhmadKhan See this.  This has the similar example as in your question.  Also many coding standards, such as MISRA, consider your code a bug, even though it "looks ok".

See what happens if you change your increment to 0.25, or 0.225 which are powers of 2.

@PaulH I think you meant 0.125

if you print the value after the loop (with sufficient precision) you might realize that <= is not the problem here

@AlanBirtles, Yes 0.125 was what I tried to type on my phone. Thanks for the catch.
